# Keyboard shortcut to pass current selection to a method in PhpStorm

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, keyboard-shortcuts

I find it very convenient to see the option of selecting a piece of code and then press a keyboard shortcut to pass it to a method. For example, consider the following expression:

```
    $this->log("Inside validateRequest. post:  " . $this->getRequest()->getPost());
```

I want to select the following part and then press a keyboard shortcut so the IDE would ask me for a method name. I enter the method name and the whole selection is passed to the method:

```
$this->getRequest()->getPost()
```

Then I would have the following result:

```
$this->log("Inside validateRequest. post:  " . print_r($this->getRequest()->getPost(), true));
```

I was almost certain PHPStorm or Android Studio (or other JetBrains IDEs) had this option, but I cannot find any shortcut for this purpose in the available shortcuts e.g. in the Code menu.

Comment: Based on your code examples .. you want to surround your selection with some function call, right? If so -- there is no such stuff. But you may easily create a Live Template that can be used for this, something like this: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360001977739/comments/360000284800

Comment: yes, I want to surround my selection with a function call.

Comment: OK -- Live Template is a way to go right now. You may create a generic one (so you will have to complete function name every time -- see the aforementioned link) ... or create specific one where such function/method will be hardcoded. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/using-live-templates.html and https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/tutorial-creating-live-templates.html